# How to find a user by username in the client.users collection

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to give that user role by name.
So I want to get id by username.

```
let role = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'TESTrole');
let id = client.users.get("name", "TESTname"); 
let member = message.member.guild.members.get(id);
member.addRole(role);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method.

```
let user = client.users.find("username", "TESTname");
//OR
let user = client.users.find(user => user.username == "TESTname");
//once you've found the user you can get the id (or you can write .id after the find method)
let id = user.id;
```

Answer (score 5):

Old post (I know) but commenting for those using v12,

`const user = client.users.cache.find(user => user.username == "").id;`

Answer (score 1):

This

```
let id = client.user.get('name', 'name here').id;
```

should get you the results you're looking for.
See [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) for clarification of the properties you can search by and view, including id:

```
.id
  The ID of the user

  Type: Snowflake
```

Comment: let id =client.users.get('name', 'DODDO').id;
                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

DODDO is my name.

Comment: `client.user` should be `client.users` and the [`get()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) can only be used with an id.