# Discord.js how to get user id just from the username

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This isn't working:
`` client.users.cache.get(`${args[0]}`).id; ``

What should I do to fix it? I'm on v12

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229193/how-to-find-a-user-by-username-in-the-client-users-collection/51235209

Comment: It returns this error message: `TypeError: message.client.users.find is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
matching_client = client.users.cache.filter(user => user.username === args[0]);
```

`matching_client` is a Collection of users that match that username

Relevant documentation link:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter

Comment: This works but how do I make it so it just uses the id? I've tried `votefor = message.client.users.cache.filter(user => user.username === args[0]);

id = votefor.id;` But that returns undefined

Comment: You'll have to get the first element from the collection, try `id = votefor.array()[0].id`

Comment: That's a bit unnecessary, why not just user `<Collection>.find()`? that way you don't have to convert it into an array and don't have to index it by 0.