# discord.js node get user by username

Tags: discord, discord.js

There is already similar post ([How to find a user by username in the client.users collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229193/how-to-find-a-user-by-username-in-the-client-users-collection/51235209)) but it doesn't answer my question.

I could use this to find user by username:

```
client.users.find("username", "TESTname");
```

The problem is that 2 users can have the same username but different discriminator. I could use this to find user by discriminator:

```
client.users.find(user => user.discriminator == '3173')
```

The problem with this method is that two users can have the same discriminator. Is there any way to find user by both username and discriminator?

Edit:

@Elitezen suggested I can use user.tag. This works, but only if the message is from that user. I would like to get user from my discord but other than user who wrote the message.

This works only if user is the same as the message user. If it is not the same, it will return null even if this user is inside my discord. Any way to get user's data even if the user is not the same?

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
    client.users.find(user => user.tag == '<name>#<discriminator>');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`<User>.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag) property will return a string containing both the [`username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username) and [`discriminator`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=discriminator))

```js
client.users.find(user => user.tag == '<name>#<discriminator>');
```

Comment: Thank you. This partially resolved the problem, but now the other problem is that it will return null if the user is not the same as the message user (see my edit).

Comment: Have you tried fetching all users before calling `.find()`